# Calling a function of a deployed smartcontract by my smartcontract fails, while calling it using web3.py with the same bytedata succeeds

Tags: solidity, bytecode, address.call

I want to call a function of an external smartcontract using my smartcontract. I wrote the following solidity code:

```
contract main {
    
    address public toCall = theAddressToCall;
    
    function mainFunction() public {
        toCall.call(encoded_bytedata);
    } 
}
```

When I make a tx to call the mainFunction(), the tx succeeds, but the call itself seems to fail as nothing happens and I get the info 'Although one or more Error Occurred [execution reverted] Contract Execution Completed '. Unfortunately I dont have access to the external smartcontracts ABI - is there a way to catch and display the Error that is happening?

When I call the toCall.call function directly from an EOA in web3.py with the encoded_bytedata, then it succeeds just fine, with the code below:

```
tx = {
    'nonce': nonce,
    'gasPrice': w3.toWei(30, 'gwei'),
    'gas': 100000,
    'to': theAddressToCall,
    'data': encoded_bytedata
}

signed_tx = w3.eth.account.signTransaction(tx, key)
tx_hash = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
```

TLDR; I want to make a solidity smartcontract, where when I make an EOA tx ->my smartcontract->executes external smartcontract function , but this does not succeed. When I make an EOA tx -> executes external smartcontract function with web3.py, this succeeds, using the same variables. So the mistake must be in my solidity code above. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: How is `encoded_bytedata` encoded, string, bytes? I'd use abi.encode functions. instead of hard coding a string. The `call` returns two values, one of them is a bool that is true when the call was successful and false otherwise.

Comment: thanks for the comment! Unfortunately I dont have access to the ABI - I just copied the bytedata of another successful tx that called a function of the contract and doing that worked just fine with the python web3.py code at the bottom of my answer. Do you see some reason why the same bytedata wouldnt work in my own smartcontract sending the tx at the top of my answer?

Comment: A couple of thins that can go wrong are: not enough gas, wrong encoding (sending as string but it should be a bytes array), contract doesn't support calls from other contracts....

Comment: not enough gas / wrong encoding shouldnt be the case, as when sending the tx from an EOA using web3.py with the same gas limit and encoding as with the smartcontract it goes through just fine.

Contract not supporting calls from other contracts could be the reason, just dont know how to find if that sthe case - do you perhaps know whether its possible to debug the error/revert reason when using the address.call() function?

Comment: Sorry, but without more details that's all I can think of.